# In react, passing a value to a function results in 'Unterminated Template' Among other errors

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm attempting to pass a variable to a function in react so as to do some conditional rendering.

The main function `TypeIcon` calls the function `iconSwitch` and attempts to pass a variable.

If I render the text passed in the original `props` as `{props.type}` this renders fine. I just can't seem to pass it to the function. Or perhaps call the function correctly.

### TypeIcon file

```
import React from 'react';

import '../../App.css'

function iconSwitch(props) {

  switch(props.value) {
    case 'article':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-file-text';
    case 'video':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-video-camera';
    case 'audio':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-headphones';
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
}


function TypeIcon (props){

  return (
    <div>
      <iconSwitch value={props.type} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TypeIcon
```

This renders in HTML as:

`<iconswitch value="article"></iconswitch>`

And if I modify the `TypeIcon` function I get a variety of errors none of which help me figure out how to pass the value to the function. For example:

### Unexpected Token

```
function TypeIcon (props){

  return (
<div>
    <span>{props.type}</span>
    {iconSwitch({props.type})}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Returns `Unterminated Template`

### Unexpected Token

```
function TypeIcon (props){

  return (

    <span>{props.type}</span>
    $this.iconSwitch({props.type})
  )
}
```

Returns unexpected token

Comment: There's a stray ` in `{this.iconSwitch(\`{props.type})}`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that issue. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react Custom Components name must start with a capital letter . so your iconswitch component is not rendering .

you can try doing this instead

```
import React from 'react';

import '../../App.css'

function IconSwitch(props) {

  switch(props.value) {
    case 'article':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-file-text';
    case 'video':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-video-camera';
    case 'audio':
      return  <span><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>;
      //return 'fa fa-headphones';
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
}


function TypeIcon (props){

  return (
    <div>
      <IconSwitch value={props.type} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TypeIcon
```

it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, all fixed. :)